# How to show all my images in tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I only see images which are currently residing in symbolic tensor (logits, label):

```
with tf.name_scope("Train"):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(FLAGS.learning_rate).minimize(cost_function)
    tf.summary.image('logits', tn_logits, max_outputs=4)
    tf.summary.image('label', t_label, max_outputs=4)
```

In the session, I feed the network images in a loop.

```
for epoch in range(FLAGS.training_epochs):

        for img in images:
            _, summary_str, costs = sess.run([optimizer, merged_summary_op, cost_function],
                                             feed_dict={t_im0: img.l_img.eval(), t_im1: img.r_img.eval(),
                                                        t_label: img.mask.eval()})
```

How to show all images simultaneously?

---

I want to have this view for all my images like in a gallery:
[image: example]

Comment: If `tn_logits` and `t_label` are tensors with shape `[batch_size, height, width, channels]`, there will be 4 (`max_outputs=4`) images in tensorboard. Do you have a different outcome or want something else?

Comment: Yes, they have the shape [1, h, w, 1]. I just tried 4 outcomes, but it always stays for  2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first dimension of image tensor and `max_output` argument of `tf.summary.image` define number of images in tensorboard gallery. Since you write 1 image at a time, the existing images are overwritten.

Instead of iterating, concatenate 4 images such that `tn_logits` and `t_label` will have shape of `[4, h, w, 1]`.

Then in tensorboard you will have `Train/logits/image/0`, `Train/label/image/1`, `Train/label/image/2` and `Train/label/image/3` entries for `tn_logits`.

Comment: How to conatenate?

Comment: You can use `numpy.concatenate(images, axis=0)`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate

Comment: Is that possible if the batchsizes differs per batch: ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [1,246,381,3] vs. shape[1] = [1,252,367,3]

Comment: I thought images have the same `h` and `w`. Then this will not work. Images must have the same shape. You can try resizing them first.